# Link ul with Ajax Action Link?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

How can i link my 'box' with my ajax action link?

code

```
        <ul class="box">
            <li>
                <p>@item.SiteName</p>
                <div class='description'></div>
                <div class='left'></div>
                <div class='button1'></div>
                <div class='button2'></div>
                <div class='button3'></div>
            </li>
        </ul>
```

Link

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(@item.SiteName, "GetSiteApplications", "Sites", new { siteName = @item.SiteName }, new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = @item.SiteId.ToString() })
```